# Using template/generic in swift with typealias

Tags: ios, swift, templates, generics

Supposing we have a method like this:

```
func retrieve<T>(completion: (response: ResponseItems<T>?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
   /* whatever */
}
```

Until you have to call this method "directly" there are no problems:

```
service.retrieve { (response: ResponseItems<Myclass>?, error) -> Void in
        
}
```

Now the question: if I want to call this method with a generic class type?

I have:

```
enum ClassType: String {
  case FirstClass: "FirstClass"
  case SecondClass: "SecondClass"
  case FooClass: "FooClass"
}

func retrieveAll() {
  for i in 1...3 {
     /* suppose that this method returns class name from enum */
     let classStringName = self.getClassName(i)
     /* here TRICK */
     service.retrieve{ (response: ResponseItems<WHAT??>?, error) -> Void in
        
     }
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

**Notice** that all class type in enum inherit from a base class Mappable.

## update

Basically, retrieve method do a request to an API and return a jsonReponse, then I have to map it to a generic object, with [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper).

```
func retrieve<T>(completion: (response: ResponseItems<T>?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    var response : T? = nil
    response = Mapper<T>().map(jsonResponse)
    completion(response: response, error: error) 
}
```

I don't want to change retrieve function behaviuor, I want that it remain as "ignorant" as possibile and delegate the issue to the caller.

Comment: I can use "typealias" to do the trick, but I can't do working yet

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No @ABakerSmith, I don't know a method to call "retrieve" with a "dynamic" class..

Comment: when you call retrieve, do you know in advance the type of the expected responseItems? Are all the responseItems of the same type?

Comment: I have to call the method N times iterating an array of AnyObject

Comment: Can you be more specific? How do you use the AnyObject from the array to call retrieve?

Comment: this is the point.. how! (:

Comment: I mean: 1)  the retrieve function has only one parameter (the closure) 2) the closure receives a newly created object as response: or an error 3) I do not see any role for the AnyObject -- can you explain what is its job?